# Como exibir trecho de código no React?

Tags: javascript, react, aplicação-web

Estou criando uma aplicação onde preciso exibir trecho do código como exemplo, já li sobre e até consegui ter um resultado médio onde renderizava o conteúdo dentro de um `textarea`, porém gostaria que ficasse da mesma forma que aqui no stack.

Exemplo:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom'
import DescriptionHook from '../Components/DescriptionHook'

const UseMemo: React.FC = () => {
    const { url } = useRouteMatch()
    return (
        <>
            <DescriptionHook
                name={url.replace('/', '')}
                description="
                  O hook useMemo serve para memorização de valores já calculados."
            />
        </>
    )
}

export default UseMemo
```

Existe alguma lib ou alguma forma que facilite essa demanda ?

Answer (score -3):

Você pode usar a tag `<pre>` do HTML pra exibir um bloco com formatação de código (fonte de largura fixa, etc).

Caso queira exibir o código colorido, é um pouco mais complicado. Você pode pesquisar por bibliotecas que façam isso, e então seguir as instruções da biblioteca escolhida. Utilize a palavra chave "syntax hightlight" pra buscar por uma biblioteca no google. Não posso te recomendar nenhuma aqui.

PS: Me lembro agora do projeto [shiki-twoslash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shiki-twoslash), que é o código usado pra gerar os blocos de exemplo na [documentação do typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html), se interessar.